# Use variables from procedure in dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(10) ,
    @b NVARCHAR(100)

SET @a = 'value'
SET @b = ' PRINT @a '

EXEC sp_executesql @b
```

i would like as a result : 'value'
but i get the error **Must declare the scalar variable "@a"**

i need to log from SQL the parameters which was called the SP

i need this because inside SP i create the dinamic query from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS

my procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE marianTest
@a INT,
@b NVARCHAR(121)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max)
SET @query = dbo.ufn_admin_Ex(cast(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) AS nvarchar(100)))
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @query
```

where @query is like this :

```
declare @callSP nvarchar(max) = 
'DECLARE @a int = ' + CASE  WHEN @a IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE    convert(nvarchar(15),@a)     END + CHAR(13)
+', @b nvarchar(121) = ' + CASE  WHEN @b IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE + '''' + @b+   ''''     END + CHAR(13)

EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_admin_traceError] @callSp
```

thanks
Marian

Comment: If you are using MySQL please add tag "mySQL".

Comment: you refer to the inserted code ?

Comment: I don't understand how `dbo.ufn_admin_Ex` can return the code you reference. Can you try again?

Comment: the code is a text , trust me is what the function returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(10) , @b NVARCHAR(100)  
SET @a = 'value' 
SET @b = ' PRINT @a '  
EXEC sp_executesql @b, N'@a nvarchar(10)', @a
```

Result:

```
value
```

Comment: EXEC sp_executesql @b, N'@a nvarchar(10)', @a  
I can't use @a because i don't know the name of parameter
i get it from code :  
SELECT PARAMETER_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
WHERE   SPECIFIC_NAME = 'marianTest'

Comment: You cannot execute a script inside a select, so you need to put parameter_name inside a variable or a cursor and if using a cursor loop through the results. While executing the script. While doing this you can populate @a with the parameter

Answer (score 2):

`@b` can't magically see `@a` unless you introduce them somehow.

Try before the exec:

```
SET @b = 'PRINT ''' + @a + ''';
```

Or you can use `sp_executesql` this way instead:

```
DECLARE @b NVARCHAR(100);

SET @b = N'PRINT @a';

EXEC sp_executesql @b, N'@a NVARCHAR(10)', @a;
```

Comment: SET @b = ' PRINT @a '  
the dinamic query i get from other function (input parameter procedure name), there is a 100 line functione , and i want it in more procedures  
, so i need some magic

Comment: You need to show us what you ACTUALLY want to do, not some trivial representation.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the parameters on

```
exec sp_executesql
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parameters/variables in your dynamic SQL you should use `sp_executesql` with parameters. See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql) for an excellent introduction to dynamic SQL.

Comment: He is using it on the last line:
`EXEC sp_executesql @b`

Comment: @Bridge Damn, you are right. But he is using it in a wrong way, so the link is still a valid answer.

Comment: He needs to add parameters to it though, hence my link for the example! :-)

I definitely recommend Erland's page though, I have it favourited already.

Comment: @Bridge Reworded my answer, now it should fit. The sommarskog link is the best article on dynamic SQL you can get. If the OP still has questions after reading that article it will get interesting ;)